# Problems with Memory Initialization in Quartus

Tags: vhdl, memory, quartus, rom

I have the following code snippet in my VHDL code to initialize a ROM block:

```
type graphics is array(0 to 307199) of std_logic;
signal disp : graphics;
attribute ram_init_file : string;
attribute ram_init_file of disp : signal is "vga_init.mif";
```

When I compile the code (Quartus 16.0) I get the following warning:

```
Warning (10541): VHDL Signal Declaration warning at shotbot.vhd(23): used implicit default value for signal "disp" because signal was never assigned a value or an explicit default value. Use of implicit default value may introduce unintended design optimizations.
```

Like the warning implies, this causes the signal to revert to its default when I access it later, using `disp(index)`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening or possible fixes?

Comment: Is this snippet wrapped in something that looks like the block RAM architecture of your FPGA? If your memory doesn't look like a memory to the tool, the tool can't infer it as such. Looks like this is a VGA buffer, although only 1-bit data. VGA is usually at *least* 8-bit (3 red, 3 green, 2 blue). If you really want 1-bit pixels (`std_logic`), you may still have to define the memory as a vector type (`std_logic_vector`) with width 1 (0 downto 0). Do your RAM dimensions (307200 x 1) match the format of your .mif file? And does your FPGA have enough block RAM to fit this structure?

Comment: It is VGA, but I'm only using black and white, everything is 1-bit (it's extended to the full 8 bits later).  I tried a 1-bit unsigned vector, but not std_logic_vector, I'll have to try that.

Comment: Update: Changing "std_logic" to "std_logic_vector(0 downto 0) worked.  For posterity's sake, is there a list of what types will and won't work with such an arrangement?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I imagine there's some Altera/Intel documentation on it somewhere. My initial thought would've been any bit vector type. I am surprised `unsigned` didn't work.